# Gitlab 16.0 CE return error on a simple gitlab-ci file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ci.yml

Today I updated my Gitlab CE to latest version 16.0.4 but after that I couldn't run pipeline on my old projects.

Installation type:
Self-managed (sudo apt install gitlab-ce)

The version of the runner:
16.0.2

Executor:
Docker

Default image:
Python 3.8

I using docker a runner.

I set CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true" in variables and getting below detail:

> shell not found
> **Cleaning up project directory and file based variables**
>
> - set -o
> - grep pipefail
> - set -o pipefail
> - set -o errexit
> - set +o noclobber
> - :
> - **eval '$'''rm''' -f /builds/xx/xxxxx.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE**
>   '
>   ++ rm -f /builds/xx/xxxxx.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
> - exit 0
>   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

My gitlab-ci file like:

```
stages: 
  - build
  - test
variables:
  CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
build the car:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

test the car:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ls
```

I tried to run this file on a new project and it works perfectly.

I think Gitlab couldn't run the below command:
rm -f /builds/xx/xxxxx.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE

Comment: What type of installation? What version are the runners? What executor is being used? What is the default image if the executor is type `docker`?

Comment: The installation type:
sudo apt install gitlab-ce

The version of the runner:
16.0.2

Executor:
Docker

Default image:
Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Your error message "shell not found" is the primary clue.

The issue is that your default image, `python:3.8` has no `ENTRYPOINT` defined but has a `CMD` [defined as](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/db8907eb3797ad147b59759aa1e6d7708a3fc2ce/3.8/alpine3.18/Dockerfile#LL158C16-L158C16) `python3`

When GitLab tries to run this container, instead of getting a POSIX shell, it instead runs `python` interpreter. Hence the error message of a missing shell.

You can work around this issue in the following manner:

```yaml
test-job:
  image:
    name: python:3.8-alpine
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
...
```

Alternatively, you can use a different image which does define an `ENTRYPOINT` or a `CMD` which is a valid shell.

Comment: I used python:3.8 for same project along 3 years but I faced with this problem since the Gitlab updated to 16.0.4. I have to find an alternative image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. GitLab overrides the command for containers, so the fact that the image uses a `CMD` that's not a shell is not a problem. Using the official `python:3.8` image should work fine in GitLab CI, and it does on GitLab.com

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to gitlab-ee and gitlab-runner as same in docker network

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#configure-a-network-with-container-links

So I changed `network_mode` `bridge(default)` to `host`

```
  [runners.docker]
    network_mode = "host"
```